# SQL DataReader into Arrays

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
//request.Data = new double[] { 221, 428, 492, 471, 413, 344, 294 };  -->Dummy Data    
requestReport.Data =  PurchaseSpProvider.GetRequestReportData();

public static double[] GetRequestReportData()
{            
    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = SqlManager.Instance.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetRequestReportToDays"))
    { 
        // what here?          
    }
}
```

I have never tried reading array with sql before. How can I read array type value with datareader?

Comment: You can't store an array of anything in SQL, it just doesn't make sense. We need to see how exactly the data is stored to be able to help you

Comment: Are you asking how to read an array from the database? There are no arrays in SQL Server. Or are you asking how to load the results into an array? Use a `List<double>` and add items to it while you iterate over the results. You can reduce the boilerplate if you use eg Dapper and `double[] results=connection.Query<int>(sql).ToArray()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataReader.Read()` in `while loop` to get data.

```cs
//request.Data = new double[] { 221, 428, 492, 471, 413, 344, 294 };  -->Dummy Data    
requestReport.Data =  PurchaseSpProvider.GetRequestReportData();

public static double[] GetRequestReportData()
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>();            
    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = SqlManager.Instance.ExecuteReader(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetRequestReportToDays"))
    { 

        while (dataReader.Read()) {
          list.Add(dataReader.GetDouble(0));   // 0: is your index, it can be 0, 1, 2,... based on your column index
        }
    }

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: what if the list is of class type?

Comment: @ÇağlaErdem you mean the list of return data from the stored procedure or what?

Comment: '                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    DTOReport dtoRequestReport = new DTOReport();
                    dtoRequestReport.TotalCount = dataReader.GetDouble("TotalCount", 0);
                    list.Add(dtoRequestReport);
                }

            }
                return list.ToArray(); //error '

Comment: @ÇağlaErdem why you want the data return of `GetRequestReportData()` is `double[]` and you get data is list of `DTOReport`?

Comment: `dataReader.GetDouble("TotalCount", 0);` -> `dataReader.GetDouble(index);` `dataReader.GetDouble()` just have 1 parameter input, that's the index of your return list.